# Php file pathing adding an additional folder, need help to fix this file path error

Tags: php, file, path

I have a Folder Called PHT and inside this folder is: image folder, includes folder, home folder, sources folder, and tours folder.

In my tours folder, There's a file called tours.html.php and there's a php code below:

The header.inc.html.php code is below:

```
<?php
define('BASE_URL', '/cas225/pht/');
?>
```

My problem is, when I try to go to the tours.html.php 
the file path created is:
http://localhost/cas225/pht/tours/images/portlandhistoricaltoursheader.png

The correct file path is:
http://localhost/cas225/pht/images/portlandhistoricaltoursheader.png

As you can see it adds in the tours folder somehow and I don't know how to undo this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirname( __FILE__ )` instead of baseURL.

```
 <?php include(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/pht/images/portlandhistoricaltoursheader.png'); ?>
```

Comment: it would mess up my other file path if i used this.

Comment: How this would mess up with other files?